# Trouble applying color scale to Plotly with Pandas and Cuflinks

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to apply a color scale to a graph that I'm generating from a dataframe using pandas, plotly and cuflinks.

It's breaking if I try to use a certain colorscale:

```
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
import colorlover as cl
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
from IPython.display import HTML

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
```

Here are my colorscales, both of which I can display fine like this:

```
bupu = cl.scales['9']['seq']['BuPu']
cs12 = cl.scales['12']['qual']['Paired']
HTML(cl.to_html(cs12))
```

If I create a plot using 'bupu' it works great, however if I attempt he same with 'cs12' I get an error:

This works:

```
df.iplot(kind='bar',colorscale='bupu')
```

This does not:

```
df.iplot(kind='bar',colorscale='cs12')
```

> KeyError: 'cs12'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-marker-colorscale):

> `colorscale` must be an array containing arrays mapping a normalized value to an
>   rgb, rgba, hex, hsl, hsv, or named color string. [...]
>
> Alternatively,
>   `colorscale` may be a palette name string of the following list:
>   Greys, YlGnBu, Greens, YlOrRd, Bluered, RdBu, Reds, Blues, Picnic,
>   Rainbow, Portland, Jet, Hot, Blackbody, Earth, Electric, Viridis

In order to use the colorlover module you could create the color array and then assign the variable to `colorscale`, e.g.

```
import colorlover, plotly

cs12 = colorlover.scales['12']['qual']['Paired']

plotly.plotly.plot(data=[{
  'colorscale': cs12
  'z': [[10, 100.625, 1200.5, 150.625, 2000],
       [5000.625, 60.25, 8.125, 100000, 150.625],
       [2000.5, 300.125, 50., 8.125, 12.5],
       [10.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6000.25, 100.625],
       [0, 0.625, 2.5, 50000.625, 10]],
  'type': 'heatmap'
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

I just created my own custom pallet

```
mycolors = ['#F81106','#FA726C','#F8C1BE',
            '#137503','#54B644','#B2F5A7',
            '#051E9B','#4358C0','#A6B3F9',
           '#9C06A0','#C34BC6','#F3A1F6',
           '#A07709','#CDA742','#F4DC9D',
           '#08A59E','#4DD5CE','#AAF7F3']

colors=mycolors
```